# What hand and finger exercises help with climbing?

Tags: climbing, exercises

It's been a while since I went rock climbing but I'd like to get back into it. What are some hand exercises that will help with climbing?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: Climbing is more about using the right technique so that you do not have to rely on your hand and finger strength too much. Obviously, you can do way more squats than you can do pullups.

Comment: to answer the Bella's question - I use some of those products as a way to warm up when I'm driving to the climbing gym / crag.  But I don't think that any of them are all that good at building finger strength.  @Bella - do you have access to a climbing gym or outdoor climbing where you could actually climb 2 or more times a week?  You'll see good progress from doing that, esp. if you're a beginner.  You can include other stuff in your training plan (like hangboards), but they come with a risk of injury, and you need to know how to fit them in and adjust your training plan to be safe.

Comment: FWIW, I like this one:  http://www.rei.com/product/478026/power-putty-hand-strengthener
I find the putty lets me move my fingers in a natural pattern, and provides a decent amount of resistance.
I've also used the Black Diamond "O-Ring" gripper, but I don't like it, some times I can catch my finger from a bad angle and aggrevate old injuries. YMMV.

Comment: Use a hangboard/fingerboard. Do a 20-minute exercise twice a week. Be consistent. Don't climb the day after a real 20-minute handboard routine (to exhaustion).

Comment: I voted for @patrick-scott's answer just to go climbing. You or others searching this question would benefit from the pooled knowledge in [/r/climbharder](https://www.reddit.com/r/climbharder/wiki/index).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to using a [Finger exerciser](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=finger%20exerciser&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=9680200230582055245&sa=X&ei=gNAhT8W1J8XHswbYoMTaBw&ved=0CIcBEPMCMAA), I do the following:

- Squeezing plasticene or stress balls
- Dumb-bell curls
- Chin-ups, both on a bar, and finger chin-ups on a door frame or similar
- Press-ups on fingertips

These give finger, hand, wrist and forearm strength - worthwhile using them together. The thing I'm not so good at is toughening up the backs of my fingers. I play guitar, so my fingertips are nicely callused, but I always scuff the backs of my fingers when trying to jam into cracks.

Comment: Can you trace these recommendations to advice from major climbing training guides?  Links?

Stress balls may provide an adequate warm up, but don't come close to the strain of supporting your weight on your fingers.  On the other hand, door jam pullups and finger tip pushups can be extremely strenuous for beginners or non-athletes who are trying to get into climbing.

I'm not saying you wouldn't get some strength from these exercises, but that these would either only make minor contributions, or be very injurious for a beginner.

Comment: They are all just simple steps - the stress balls can be used by anyone, and finger chin-ups and fingertip press-ups are just a logical progression from ordinary ones. Definitely not injurious - I even have my kids doing these now, and they are 10 and 12

Comment: I didn't reply for a while, but I have to respectfully disagree...  people come into climbing from all sorts of backgrounds.  You're kids are no doubt healthy, young, and fairly lightweight, and doing pullups on a medium sized rail might be fine for them.  There are also guys that start climbing in middle age, and might be a good bit overweight.  I couldn't recommend fingertip pullups for them (even if they can do regular pullups), becuase I don't know anything about their general finger strength.

Comment: On fitness.stackexchange.com, there's a habit of asking posters for a lot of personal info before recommending a workout routine.  That might fit this question - depending on who you are, hangboard work / fingertip pullups MIGHT be great, or it MIGHT be a bad idea.

Comment: Well, I'm a slightly overweight but reasonably fit IT guy. If I can do it, anyone can.

Comment: so can I, that's not the point.

Comment: that's my personal info bit - what more do you need dude?

Comment: Your argument was that because you can do it, every beginning climber should be able to as well.  Which is not true.  That was precisely what I was disagreeing with.  I'm happy that it works for you.  I didn't mean this as a personal attack. :)  Its just out of line with the experiences of friends of mine, and inconsistent with training recommendations that surround hangboards and campus boards.

Comment: Okay - I think it isn't out of reach of folks like me who are in their 40's, a bit overweight and having a sedentary job, to be able to go from normal pullups to fingertip pullups in a matter of a few weeks. But I am not a medical professional - I climb with a few folks who are much fitter than me and try to keep up. You may be absolutely correct. This post was just my experience.

Comment: hey man, I'm sorry.  I got a bit snippier than I meant to.  I went back to edit my comment, but you had already replied to it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6647/discussion-between-rory-alsop-and-davidr)

Comment: For people who want a great rundown of climbing fitness, and studies about why it works please check out the following book "Performance Rock Climbing". http://www.amazon.com/Performance-Rock-Climbing-Dale-Goddard/dp/0811722198

Answer (score 20):

Climbing is the best exercise for finger and hand strength improvement, just make sure to warm up and stretch.

EDIT:

Just want to defend my answer. There are a lot of books out there you can read about climbing for training. Many of them will tell you not to waste your time cross training. The best training for climbing, is climbing.

Now if you are advanced there are other methods, but the useful ones are directly related to climbing.

The most obvious are fingerboards. Do dead hangs and pull ups in all different finger positions and different common climbing holds.

The next is H.I.T., or "Hypergravity Isolation Training", where using HIT boards you can follow a regimen to work solely on hand strength while still in a climbing format. You can train pinches crimps, and varying pocket sizes with different finger combinations.

There are also campus boards which are wooden boards with varying degrees of crimping difficulty which are ridiculously difficult and strenuous and should only be used by top tier climbers or you will injure yourself.

Now, with all these methods in mind, just climbing a wall will do wonders to improve your hand strength, whether it be top-roping, lead, or bouldering (or other).

So don't worry about cross training, just go climb a wall. When you really hit a plateau (Probably around the 5.10 going into 5.11 level or later), look into HIT.

Comment: why does this get a down vote. I'm serious. The best way to improve your finger strength IS climbing. Other finger exercises are not as beneficial as climbing is.

Comment: you could do any of the following:
    Squeezing plasticene or stress balls
    Dumb-bell curls
    Chin-ups, both on a bar, and finger chin-ups on a door frame or similar
    Press-ups on fingertips

But if you just climb instead, you will see more finger and hand strength improvement.

Comment: I guess it got a downvote because you didn't answer the question.

Comment: I was going to give the same answer, then saw yours. Yes, this is the best exercise. Nothing else comes close to the amount of strength you gain from climbing.

Answer (score 11):

If you haven't climbed in a while I would recommend staying away from doing fingertip pull-ups on hang boards.  My assumption is that you are out of climbing shape and tendons and ligaments are easy to injure and take a long time to heal.  This is coming from someone who has been climbing for around 8 years off and on and has made many mistakes, please learn from mine.  Over all, take it slow when returning from a hiatus.

Available products I have used without injury are the powerball and the grippers.  Both are small and can be used when you might otherwise be wasting time, like waiting in line at a store.

For further advise I would suggest reading [Training For Climbing](http://trainingforclimbing.com/).  It is edited by a well known, longtime (34 years) climber on the east coast, Eric Hörst.  He is also frequently featured (74 times!) in a podcast called Pod Climber, giving training advice.  I found this valuable as I could listen in the car.

Comment: Training for climbing is a fine book on the subject, if you're serious about improving your fitness this is a great place to start.

Answer (score 9):

## Building Grip Strength

Your best chances to improve your fingertip strength is performing excercises specific to those ligaments at or near body weight.

Balls, rings, and grip springs are good for warming up, but not increasing strength.

**But** you need to be careful if you are just starting out because you can easily **injure yourself** by overtraining.

**Please do not just throw yourself into 50 pull ups a day... you will tear a tendon/ligament inside of 6 weeks.**

## Great Training Book

The best reference that I know of on climbing training is called "Performance Rock Climbing" and is one of the great books about improving climbing fitness. Highly recommended.

**Note: Yes it was written in the early 90's, it is still amazing.**

[image: Performance Rock Climbing]

## Training Aids

[image: Resistance Bands]

Use resistance bands to **decrease** force for high rep pull up workouts.

Alternatively you can use them to **increase** force for short intense workouts.

[image: Wooden Finger Board]

Use the finger board to isolate the grip area to your 1st or 2nd knuckle, and reduce the number of fingers on the board for increased intensity.

### Last note...

## READ PERFORMANCE ROCK CLIMBING

Comment: I've been climbing for a few years now and there is nothing as helpful as those finger boards. I hate them, but they are really the best way to train.

Answer (score 6):

The most common for rock climbing are with fingerboards or campus boards.

Without those, you can perform dead hangs on anything you can hold onto, such as pullup bars. To make it a little more difficult, you can dead hang on the edges of doorways.

There are other handheld devices for grip strengthening, such as tiger claws.

Lastly, wrist curls with dumbbells will also strengthen forearms which will help when climbing.

Comment: Fingerboards and campus boards should be used with extreme caution especially if you are not "climbing fit" already. Large amounts of rest between reps, and probably avoid the campus board at all.

Comment: I'll second this.  Most training guides (Eric Horst, others), will caution against the use of finger boards unless you're ALREADY leading 5.12 or bouldering V5.  And that's a pretty advanced standard.

Answer (score 6):

If I already had the right to vote I would give a **+1** to [Patrick Scott](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/217/patrick-scott)'s answer. Probably the best hand and finger exercises that help with climbing are the ones actively performed while climbing! And the key to strengthen fingers as best as possible, is to actively work on different styles of climbing. In other words, trying all kinds of imaginable grips!

Beginners worrying about injuries should just start-up with easy climbs (problems/routes) which feature big pocket-like grips and slowly advance in harder/smaller, all kinds of grips.

Most of the alternatives to "train" fingers (including various squeezing balls, dumb-bell curls, chin-ups, finger chin-ups, press-ups on fingertips) would be better a choice for recovering from injuries, trying to perform equally distributed muscle training (having in mind for example isometric exercises) to avoid various effects caused by over-training specific groups of muscles, or really targeting at being able to hold on very specific grips/holds.

Answer (score 4):

As well as squeezing stress balls and pulling on fingerboards, I bought a [powerball](http://www.powerballs.com/) a few years ago after one of my friends lent me his. It really helps with the wrist and forearm, and if you get the RPM counter, you can have a bit of fun, too.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common question for beginners to ask.  Climbing feels overwhelmingly strenuous when you're starting out.  There are a variety of exercises that are recommended to strengthen your fingers, I can enumerate them below, but some are given in other answers.  But I want to emphasize the following:

**If you have access to a climbing gym, or live somewhere with outdoor rocks accessible after work, you will get significantly better gains in your climbing ability from just climbing 2 or more times a week, consistently, that you will from pure finger-strength training.  Especially if you're a beginner.**

If you've been climbing for a while and are looking to supplement your training, or if you just can't climb all that frequently you could consider the following:

Using general fitness equipment:

- Finger curls with a barbell:  http://www.nicros.com/training/articles/eastern-bloc-training-heavy-finger-rolls/
- Deadhangs from a pullup bar.  Try to keep your arms slightly bent, and hang for as long as you can.  Try to build up to 4 minutes.  Be careful, this can be hard on your shoulders.  I personally can't do this exercise because of shoulder problems, but have friends that can.

Specialized pieces of climbing equipment:

- Metolius Rock Rings: http://www.metoliusclimbing.com/rock_rings.html
- a hangboard: http://www.backcountry.com/store/search.html?mv_session_id=UmsK5WiA&q=hangboard

With either of these you would want to do dead-hangs (like on the pullup bar), and focus on the larger holds for the first few months.  **I don't know what your fitness background is, but both of these can should be considered "high risk" devices.  They're designed by and for experienced rock climbers.  They're targeted at people who are already climbing 5.12 sport climbs or V5 boulder problems.  If you're not at a similar level of fitness, you could easily injure youself using them.  Climbers regularly put their hands into positions that can only be considered orthopedic-ally unsafe when they grip tiny holds.**

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using the Grip Saver Plus from Metolius. It has the advantage of not only exercising your finger pressure, but the inverse. Witch from what I've heard from a physiotherapist is good thing. There were a theory behind that I don't remember well, but from what I remember the main idea is that you have to exercise the inverse of the tendon to gain strength in that tendon.

http://www.metoliusclimbing.com/grip_saver_plus.html