# finger grip improvement exercisers

Tags: climbing, rock-climbing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hand and finger exercises help with climbing?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/547/what-hand-and-finger-exercises-help-with-climbing)

I'm looking to get a product that will improve my finger grip- have been looking at powerballs & grip masters but cannot decide which would be better!

Can anyone help me out/give me any advice on these products?